# How to post a big string/json using AJAX on Play Framework 1.4.x

Tags: java, json, ajax, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a JSON that looks more or less like this:

`{"id":"id","date":"date","csvdata":"csvdata".....}`

where csvdata property is a big amount of data in JSON format too.
I was trying to POST this JSON using AJAX in Play! Framework 1.4.x so I sended just like that, but when I receive the data in the server side, the csvdata looks like [object Object] and stores it in my db.

My first thought to solve this was to send the csvdata json in string format to store it like a longtext, but when I try to do this, my request fails with the following error:

`413 (Request Entity Too Large)`

And Play's console show me this message:

`Number of request parameters 3623 is higher than maximum of 1000, aborting. Can be configured using 'http.maxParams'`

I also tried to add http.maxParams=5000 in application.conf but the only result is that Play's console says nothing and in my database this field is stored as null.

Can anyone help me, or maybe suggest another solution to my problem?

Thanks you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you check the content of `cvsdata` field in your controller with `http.maxParams=5000` ?

Comment: Hi @RémiLavolée I checked it using JPDA on Eclipse. With http.maxParams=5000 my controller receives nothing, a null string, but in the console I have no error message.

Comment: Ok. We need to know where the problem comes from. Have try to send a light version of `csvdata` ? How do you deserialize the json content in the controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you sent "csvdata" as an array, not a string?  Each element in the array would be a separate parameter.  I have sent 100KB strings using AJAX and not run into the http.maxParams limit.  You can check the contents of the request body using your browser's developer tools.

If your csvdata originates as a file on the client's machine, then the easiest way to send it is as a File.  Your controller action would look like:

```
public static void upload(String id, Date date, File csv) {
   ...
}
```

When Play! binds a parameter to the File type, it writes the contents of the parameter to a temporary file which you can read in.  (This avoids running out of memory if a large file is uploaded.)  The File parameter type was designed for a normal form submit, but I have used it in AJAX when the browser supported some HTML5 features (File API and Form Data).